# Transparent cache when querying time series with Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have time series data, as daily parquet file of 3 GB in HDFS (`hdfs:///data/year=X/month=X/day=X/data.parquet.gz`), warehouse'd by Hive as data table.

All night, we run SQL queries to generate reports, with Apache Spark:

```
(1) SELECT date, count(*) from data GROUP BY date
```

(of course we have more complex query ^^)

I notice Apache Spark will run the query on all our data set (which is normal), but I would like to re-use data of previous day if possible since the previous data never change.

**Solution in place**

I can achieve this by doing an incremental consolidation:

`(2) INSERT INTO consolidation SELECT date, count(*) FROM data WHERE date="yesterday"`

then run the query against it (`(3) SELECT date, value FROM consolidation`)

**Transparent cache I want**

I am wondering if it's possible to have this behavior with the query (1) maybe by hacking how Spark is generating the `logical plan`, I dont know.

Comment: What you want is a _materialized view_ and requires (a) massive R&D efforts and (b) a way to detect which segments of data have changed since large materialization. Since Spark is not a DBMS and cannot ensure the data files have not changed in the meantime, it can't do it. For the record, Horton (RiP) tries to introduce that feature in Hive 3 but only for "ACID tables" that are under full control of Hive. For the record also, the MVs in Oracle have been there for a decade and are still a bit tricky to work with...

Comment: Some questions: 1. Is each days data appended to previous data or each wriiten to separate files? 2. Can you change the writing application? 3. Do you just need data for 2 days together or any range? 4. Can you use the data frame API?

Comment: If you have count distinct over periods greater than one day, reusing pre-aggregated results from previous days would be problematic.

Comment: Data IS appended in new folder, previous data never changed , thats why i think its possible tout achieve this "transparently"